CURL for http request
This is for my project. My professor is strict. He wants us to get requests only from http.request. I have an API that has a cURL get request.
I'm using the following code to execute a rest API using Curl with Node.JS. It is working on my local machine.
What is the parameter format for http.request(cURL)
I tried to use multiple formatting examples on Node.js http documentation

What do you mean? Do you mean you want to parse a curl syntax and run the request in nodejs? Like request("curl https://reqbin.com/echo/get/json -H \"Accept: application/json\"")? Or you want to request with http.get?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
